# How to start clangd via web socket

Tags: llvm, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol, clangd, monaco-languageserver

I wanted to integrate Clangd with Monaco Editor and while trying to achieve this I found that I can't start Clangd via Web Sockets.

When I run `clangd` in my terminal, it outputs `Starting LSP over stdin/stdout`, is there a way to let it launch a web socket server or do I have to implement this myself? I'm aware that the Python LSP has a `--ws` flag you can turn on to start a server. But I didn't find something like that with Clangd.

Or is there a better way to integrate Clangd with Monaco Editor? I'm currently going with [Monaco Language Client](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it may be helpful to look at how the [Theia IDE](https://theia-ide.org/) does it -- I believe it uses the Monaco Editor and can connect to clangd as a language server.

Comment: There's seriously no one who has implemented this as a project? I couldn't find a single post/website regarding this. I mean this sounds like such a great idea for a side project. Or maybe it isn't as simple as i thought this would be.

Comment: have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

[Success Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Ips.png)

You can use a proxy server that convert clangd stdout to websocket, like that:

1. Run [jsonrpc-ws-proxy](https://github.com/wylieconlon/jsonrpc-ws-proxy), with `servers.yml`:

```html
langservers:
  cpp:
    - clangd 
    - --compile-commands-dir
    - /proj
```

**Notice** that the `/proj` dir must cotains the `compile_commands.json` file that can generate by `bear` tool (`apt install -y bear`).

2. reference to [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/main/packages/examples/main/src/client/main.ts) client example, and integrate to Monaco Editor